# How can I get rewritten URL in JavaScript (or otherwise) from IIS Rewrite module?

Tags: javascript, html, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm writing HTML pages for a single page application, and want to publish it to my current ASP hosting, so I'm using the IIS URL Rewrite module to send a lot of requests to /index.html. I'm sending them like this:

```
<rule name="Section">
  <match url="sections/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html?section={R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

What I'd like to do is get the rewritten query string with JavaScript, though this seems like an impossibility. Is there a way in a static html page to get the rewritten query string?  window.location.href is the original url, not the rewritten one.

Comment: Could you give four example urls - two entered urls and the resulting rewritten ones? And clarify which url you would like to get via javascript?

Comment: blah.com/sections/range -> blah.com/index.html?section=range, blah.com/sections/input -> blah.com/index.html?section=input. I'd like to get the rewritten query string, if possible (I realize I could parse it out of the original url, and will do so if not possible).

Comment: Could you use the [Response Headers](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Setting_Response_Headers) to include the new rewritten url `.../index.html?section=range` in the http header and read it in via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to simply dump the rewritten URL as part of the response body:

```
<input type="hidden" id="__rewritten_url" value="<%=Request.ServerVariables("URL")%>" />
```

Alternatively, you can append the rewritten URL as a `Response Header` then issue an `Ajax` request and extract that header from it. so your `web.config` would look something like:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Section">
                 <match url="sections/(.*)" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html?section={R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="AppendRewrittenResponseHeader" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_URL" pattern="*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{URL}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Then in your client side (using `jQuery` for brevity):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        url: location.href,
        success: function(message,text,response)
              {
              var myRewrittenUrl = response.getResponseHeader('URL');
              }
    });
```

Comment: It's a static .html page, I'm only using IIS because I have ASP hosting. The second solution might work though, thanks!